# JavaScript - Constructor using Prototype

Tags: javascript, function, constructor, prototype

I have a question relating with using if statement within my prototype constructor.

What I am trying to do:

1. Create a method calculatePrice for the Item constructor.
2. This method will return the price of the object by default.
3. Item is fruit, return the price of the Item minus 5%.

Code
    **  NOT WORKING

```
function Item(name, price){
  this.name = name;
  this.price = price;
}

Item.prototype.calculatePrice = function() {
  if (this.name === 'fruit') {
      this.price = this.price * 0.95
  } else {
      this.price = this.price;
  }
}

var ball = new Item('soccer ball', 15);
ball.calculatePrice();
// Expected results: 15

var fruit = new Item('fruit', 10);
fruit.calculatePrice();
// Expected results: 9.5
```

However my error is how I wrote the if statement.  Without giving me the solution, could you please direct me on where my mistake was made? Thank you.

Comment: and what's the problem with the above code?

Comment: I dont see any error, what is the problem?

Comment: The same for me. I can't investigate an error

Comment: Voting to close as problem can't be reproduced.

Comment: method calculatePrice should have a return statement, rathen than mutating price. That is the issue, I suppose

Comment: I am getting undefined in my results.  I have updated my question to show my expected results.

Comment: Tip: Don't put the working code in the middle of your question. It should remain a question. People visiting SO will look for the answer among the answers.

Comment: Done.  Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You didn't describe what are your expectations and actual outcome of your code. But one thing that came to mind is, that you forgot to return `this.price` in your calculatePrice method, so result is `undefined` instead of price. You get result even with your current version, but you have to do it explicitly by checking price property of an instance eg. `fruit.price`. And also price will mutate with every calculatePrice method call. Instead assign `this.price` to local variable, do the calculation on that variable and return it.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that if you call the method repeatedly, the price will keep decreasing (for fruit).

Also the `else` clause is doing nothing really: you assign a value that was already assigned.

Instead of storing the calculation result back in `this.price`, *return* it as the function result. That way `this.price` remains the same (no unexpected side effects), and can be controlled by the user of the object. The method then only *returns* the result:

```
var result = fruit.calculatePrice();
```

Now `fruit.price` will still be the original 10, but `result` will be 9.5

Optionally, you could let the function store the result also as an object property, but then it should better be a different one (e.g. `this.calculatedPrice`).

NB: As requested, the actual solution code is not provided. Let me know if you need more.

Comment: Thank you for the tip on the else statement.

Answer (score 0):

UPDATE:  Working Code:

```
function Item(name, price){
  this.name = name;
  this.price = price;
}

Item.prototype.calculatePrice = function() {
  if (this.name === 'fruit') {
      return 0.95 * this.price;
 } else {
      return this.price;
  }
}

var ball = new Item('soccer ball', 15);
ball.calculatePrice();
// => 15

var fruit = new Item('fruit', 10);
fruit.calculatePrice();
// => 9.5
```